# Loading news in both iOS Simulator 4 and 3.5 inches

Tags: iphone, ios

I am searching News from rss feeds in my app . It is working in iOS Simulator 4 inch bit not working in iOS Simulator 3.5 inch . My nib is same. Any suggestions regarding this problem? 
Thanks in advance. The code is given below.

```
    -(void)DownLoad:(NSNumber *)path{
        NSAutoreleasePool *pl = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        int index1 = [path intValue];
        NSString *Link = [ImgesName objectAtIndex:index1];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Link]]]; 
        if((img)&&([path intValue]<[ImgesName count]))
        {
            [dicImages_msg setObject:img forKey:[ImgesName objectAtIndex:index1]];
        }
        else
        {
            if([path intValue]<[ImgesName count])
            {
                [dicImages_msg setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"noImageAvailable.jpg"] forKey:[ImgesName objectAtIndex:index1]];
            }
        }
        [pl drain];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadScrolview) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the nib is the same in both. What you need is to dynamically change the view height based on the type of phone it is. Finding the height can be accomplished by the following line of code `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].height`.